# Is there a way to change a matching object returned from a regex.search() function?

Tags: python, regex

I am new to coding and made up a project for my self to start learning, but I could'nt get around this problem. i am trying to make a little tool which converts stuff from the clipboard(which for now I will simply use a string called `spam`) so that the sentences start with a capital letter, and in which ' i ' is also uppercase, so ' I '.

So what I tried to do was, find a match where there is a ('. ', '? ' or ' i ') and go from there.

```
spam='this is a string which i want to correct. as you can see.'
def capital(lists):            #finds out where to change the text
    dotRegex=re.compile(r'\. ')
    questionRegex=re.compile(r'\? ')
    iRegex=re.compile(r' i ')
    mo1=dotRegex.search(lists)
    mo2=questionRegex.search(lists)
    mo3=iRegex.search(lists)
    if mo1:
        (lists(mo1.start()+2)).upper()
    if mo2:
        (lists(mo1.start()+2)).upper()
    if mo3:
        mo3.upper()
capital(spam)
```

This returns the error:

> "(lists(mo1.start()+2)).upper() TypeError: 'str' object is not
>   callable"

What I try to do there is find where there is a `mo`, go 2 indecises to the right and change what is there to uppercase. Is there any way to do this? And offcourse the `search()` function only returns 1 `mo`, 
**so my question is:** is there a way to work around it when there are multiple matching objects and change them all? I know `findall()` exists but how can you use that here?

Anyway, I would love some help from anybody, and I am sorry if this code hurts to watch.

Comment: You just need to use `re.sub`. The regex will look like `r'([.?!]) ([a-z])'` and in the replacement, something like `lamda m: "{0} {1}".format(m.group(1), m.group(2).upper())`

Comment: See http://ideone.com/ipjSvm

Comment: Knowing what is a sentence or not isn't as easy as you think, but if it is for learning purpose...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors (or awkwardnesses) in your code.

Here is a quick code review:

```
import re

spam = 'this is a string which i want to correct. as you can see.'

def capital(lists):
    # finds out where to change the text.
    dot_regex = re.compile(r'\. ')
    question_regex = re.compile(r'\? ')
    i_regex = re.compile(r' i ')
    mo1 = dot_regex.search(lists)
    mo2 = question_regex.search(lists)
    mo3 = i_regex.search(lists)
    if mo1:
        lists[mo1.start() + 2].upper()
    if mo2:
        lists[mo1.start() + 2].upper()
    if mo3:
        mo3.group().upper()

capital(spam)
```

1. According to the [PEP8 conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions), variable should be written in snake case. So I replace `dotRegex` by `dot_regex`,
2. Since you don't modify it in function, you can also use module-level variables (constant) for RegEx: for instance: `DOT_REGEX`.
3. Put spaces around binary operators: `mo1 = ...`.

In Python, string indexing/slicing use `[]` operator, so replace `lists(mo1.start() + 2)` by `lists[mo1.start() + 2]`. The syntax `lists(...)` is a function call, here.

Remember that in Python, [strings are immutable](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-are-python-strings-immutable): so you can't modify it, you must create a copy.

```
foo = "string"
foo[2] = "l"  # <- TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

To answer your question: No, you can't modify a string, but you can use a search/replace with RegEx to do what you want.

Here is an detailed explanation for the `dot_regex`:

```
import re

# Search the first letter after a dot (or after the begining)
dot_regex = re.compile(r"(^|\. )(.)")

def my_upper(mo):
    """ Keep the dot (group #1), turn the letter in uppercase (group #2). """
    return mo.group(1) + mo.group(2).upper()

spam = 'this is a string which i want to correct. as you can see.'
spin = dot_regex.sub(my_upper, spam)
# => This is a string which i want to correct. As you can see.
```

You can continue with other RegEx...

*Note:* to match a single "i", you can use `r"\bi\b"`:

```
# Search a single "i"
i_regex = re.compile(r"\bi\b")

spon = i_regex.sub("I", spin)
print(spon)
# => This is a string which I want to correct. As you can see.
```

You are doing a king of copy-editing, aren't you? ;-)

You can combine the rules for dot and question mark (and exclamation mark too):

```
# Search the first letter after a dot/?/! (or after the begining)
mark_regex = re.compile(r"(^|[!?.] )(.)")

spam = 'can you see? this is a string which i want to correct. as you can see! yeh!'
spif = mark_regex.sub(my_upper, spam)
# => Can you see? This is a string which i want to correct. As you can see! Yeh!
```

**TUTORIAL: [Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)**